# What does "regression of predictor onto all of the other predictors" mean?

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, multicollinearity, r-squared

I encountered a lot of references that talk about R squared
but I can't understand what the difference is between the R squared in regression of the response on the predictors and the R squared that is mentioned in the image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use all the other variables besides $X_j$ to predict $X_j$, and then we can get an $R^2$ value.

For examples, if your variables are $X_1, X_2, X_3$, we could use $X_2$ and $X_3$ to predict $X_1$ and obtain an $R^2$ value.